# Compute probability of union set of four continuous random variables in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I have four independent variables `X1, X2, X3, X4` with a standard normal distribution. I want to calculate the probability of `P(X1 > A | X2 > A | X3 > A | X4 > A)`.  I wrote a function in R that correctly calculates the probability for any value of A that's greater 0, but for any value smaller 0 the results are to small:

```
prob_union_greater <- function(x){ 
   (1 - pnorm(x))*4 - 6*((1 - pnorm(x))^2) + 3*((1 - pnorm(x))^3) - ((1 - pnorm(x))^4)  
}
```

I tried to write a similar function for the case of `P(X1 < A | X2 < A | X3 < A | X4 < A)` and here I'm faced with the opposite problem: for negative values of A it works, for positive values it doesn't.

```
prob_union_smaller <- function(x){
   pnorm(x)*4 - 6*(pnorm(x)^2) + 3*(pnorm(x)^3) - (pnorm(x)^4)  
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How did you derive this formula? Are your random variables independent?

Comment: Ah yes this is the Poincaré formula. It's `4*(pnorm(x)^3)`, not `3`.

Comment: Whoops, not sure why I missed that... Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the code below

```
prob_union_greater <- function(x) {
  p <- pnorm(x, lower.tail = FALSE)
  4 * p - 6 * p^2 + 4 * p^3 - p^4
}

prob_union_smaller <- function(x) {
  p <- pnorm(x)
  4 * p - 6 * p^2 + 4 * p^3 - p^4
}
```

and you will get

```
> prob_union_greater(1)
[1] 0.4989328

> prob_union_smaller(1)
[1] 0.9993664
```

Comment: It's `4 * p^3`: https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Formule_du_crible/D%C3%A9finition

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Sorry for the typo. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your functions could be more succinctly written as:

```r
prob_union_greater <- function(x) (1 - pnorm(x)) * sum(pnorm(x)^(0:3))
prob_union_smaller <- function(x) prob_union_greater(-x)
```

This gives us:

```r
prob_union_greater(-1)
#> [1] 0.9993664

prob_union_greater(0)
#> [1] 0.9375

prob_union_greater(1)
#> [1] 0.4989328
```